# How to use e.stopPropagation event when I click in the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I make sure that the click is not triggered in the parent component when I click in the child component in react?

I'm trying to use e.stopPropagation() but when I click it, I see this error

> "TypeError: e.stopPropagation is not a function"

Why is that happening ??

```
class ModuleGroup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleHidden = this.toggleHidden.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isVisible: false,
    };
  }

  toggleHidden() {
    this.setState({
      isVisible: !this.state.isVisible,
    });
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    // console.log("e.Target", e.currentTarget.textContent);
    console.log("e.Target", e);
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(this.props.id)}
        // onClick={this.handleClick}
        className="moduleGroup"
        onMouseEnter={this.toggleHidden}
        onMouseLeave={this.toggleHidden}
      >
        {this.props.id}
        <div
          value={this.props.id}
          className={`modulesSet ${this.state.isVisible && "visible"}`}
        >
          {this.props.modules &&
            this.props.modules.map((module) => (
              <Module key={module.key} id={module.key} />
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(this.props.id)}` you are passing the `id`, instead of `e`.

Consider `this.handleClick(e, this.props.id)` instead.

So your handler would look like:

```
handleClick(e, id) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, this.props.id)}

handleClick(e, id) {
  // console.log("e.Target", e.currentTarget.textContent);
  console.log("e.Target", e);
  e.stopPropagation(); // Or e.preventDefault();
}
```